# Hovering a hiding element replays the hide animation shortly after

Tags: jquery, animation, timer, hover, slide

I have 2 elements next to each other, both absolutely positioned.

```
<div class="vizual">
  <h1 class="typo">...</h1>
  <a href="#" class="typo">...</a>
</div>
```

When I hover over the first element, the other element appears next to it. There are some effects and timers going on.

```
function hoverTransfer(trigger,content){
  var t;
  $(trigger).hover(
    function(){
      clearTimeout(t);
      if ($(content).css("display") == "none") {
        $(content).show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 500);
      }
    }, function(){
      t = setTimeout(function() {$(content).hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 500)}, 550);
  });
  $(content).hover(
    function(){
      clearTimeout(t);
    }, function(){
        t = setTimeout(function() {$(content).hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 500)}, 550);
  });
};
```

It should work in a way, that when I keep mouse hovered over one of the two elements, the second element stays displayed. When I move the mouse out, after some time it slides back in.

**EDIT:** If I hover over one of the elements while the second one is hiding, it should slide back to full width. But that I can't produce too...

***PROBLEM -*** It also behaves in a way that's unwanted:
When I hover **in and out** of one of these elements **while** the second element is hiding, it replays the hiding animation again shortly after it's finished.

I tried a lot of different "solutions" (checking whether elements are animated, trying to .stop() them etc, but I could never produce the desired functionality.

Comment: If you reproduce this in jsFiddle, I think it would be a lot easier for people to help you out. :)

Comment: Also, what is the exact effect you are going for? All you have really mentioned so far is that it doesn't work the way you want it to.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sgrxH/
Hover over the red box, move your mouse out of the element, and when the green box slides back, move your mouse across one of the elements (don't hold it there, just move across it when the green box is sliding back).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation

Alright, I've drawn up what I think you're asking for. If this isn't what you were asking for, hopefully you or someone else might learn something from it. :)
[image: hovering stuff]

1. Beginning layout
2. User hovers over element 1, whereupon element 2 pops up and starts slidin'
3. At this point, the user hovers between the elements, and no reset should occur
4. User hovers out from one of the elements, in my example, element 1
5. Mouse has not been over one of the elements for n seconds and should slide like in 2. but in reverse.

I find it easier to know what needs to be done if you first outline what's needed.

Going through the steps, we can now define what we need:

1. Timer that checks how long mouse has been outside the elements that executes a "reverse animation" when `n` seconds have past
2. MouseIn, MouseOut events to clear the timer, so it doesn't do a reverse animation while the user is still hovering one of the elements
3. We need unique timers for each instance of groups, what I call instantiating. Meaning: we want to be able to do this on more than 1 block of 2 elements

### The solution

First, [here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2LCBM/8/) for you to play around with ([here's one without comments](http://jsfiddle.net/2LCBM/9/)). Hopefully there's enough comments to get you through it.

And of course, here's the code.

Javascript

```js
//default variables
var Distance = 300; //px
var BetweenOffset = 10; //px
var MouseOut = 550; //ms
var AnimationTime = 500; //ms
var Timers = new Array();

$(document).ready(function(){
    //this is just to add the default distance. I didn't specify it in the CSS, but you can do it just as well
    $("div.container div.element_2").css("left", Distance);
    //adds an attribute "unique-id" with a number, so that the timer can be associated with an element. This is necessary to be able to clear the timer, and is the basics in "instantiation 101"
    $("div.container").each(function(index, parent){
        $(parent).attr("unique-id", index);
    });

    //here's were all the magic happens
    $("div.container div.element_1, div.container div.element_2").mouseenter(function(e){
        //define some local variables
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        var id = parent.attr("unique-id");
        var element1 = parent.children(".element_1");
        var element2 = parent.children(".element_2");
        var destination = element1.width()+BetweenOffset;

        //if element2 isn't visible or is being animated, we're going to stop whatever it's doing and do a beginning animation
        if(!element2.is(":visible") || element2.is(":animated") ){
            element2.stop(true).show().animate(
                {
                    left: destination,
                    opacity: 1
                },
                AnimationTime,
                "swing"
            );
        }

        //then we're gonna clear the timer associated with this parent
        Timers[id]= clearTimeout(Timers[id]);
    }).mouseleave(function(e){
       var parent = $(this).parent();
       var id = parent.attr("unique-id");
       var element1 = parent.children(".element_1");
       var element2 = parent.children(".element_2");

       //here we set the timer using an anonymous function
       Timers[id] = setTimeout(function(){
            //Only animate if it's already showing
            if(element2.is(":visible")){
                //stop whatever it's doing and remove the animation queue
                element2.stop(true).animate(
                    {
                        "left": Distance,
                        opacity: 0
                    },
                    AnimationTime,
                    "swing",
                    function(){
                        //here we make sure it's not being displayed
                        element2.css("display", "none");
                    }
                );
            }           
       }, MouseOut);
    });
});
```

HTML

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class='element_1'>Element 1</div>
    <div class='element_2'>Element 2</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class='element_1'>Element 1</div>
    <div class='element_2'>Element 2</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class='element_1'>Element 1</div>
    <div class='element_2'>Element 2</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class='element_1'>Element 1</div>
    <div class='element_2'>Element 2</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class='element_1'>Element 1</div>
    <div class='element_2'>Element 2</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.container{
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.element_1, .element_2{
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

.element_1{
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.element_2{
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: none;
}
```

### References

Some references to the functions I use

- [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)
- [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)
- [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)
- [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)
- [.mouseenter()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)
- [.mouseleave()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)
- [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)
- [setTimeout() & clearTimeout()](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/)
- [What is instantiation?](http://searchcio-midmarket.techtarget.com/definition/instantiation)

### Final thoughts

I added some cool opacity transitions, not necessary, but.. meh.
Hopefully this will help you on your way, there might be alternatives to the one I've given you, but this is how I'd solve it.

### Edit

After a brief discussion, OT notified me of his JSFiddle. I took a look at it, and [this is what I got](http://jsfiddle.net/sgrxH/2/). The only problem that remain is that it doesn't animate while it is already animating, but that is a minor problem that not many users notice.

Comment: Wow, I honestly didn't expect anybody to go this far in trying to help! In the comments to the OP I posted a jsfiddle link in which it is more clear, but your solution is pretty close even without it... The second element should be appearing from the first element. There is only 1 instance on 1 page, so there is no need for those variables in this case... I'll try to modify it to my needs and then tell you how it went. +1 anyway, thank you!!

Comment: @SqueezCZ My example should solve your problem. Check out the timers and how they're handled. I didn't notice your jsfiddle, I'll take a look at it. Also, a +1 is given at the top of each post, and a correct answer is given by clicking the green check sign at the same place. Appreciate the rep. :)

Comment: @ShadowScripter - Actually, it seems like my reputation is too low to give you a +1. I will do it when I get there! Anyway, do you think you could modify the answer after looking at the jsfiddle? I don't need to use it in more instances, so that would make it easier to rewrite it. I'm not "new" in scripting, but I don't think I'll able to modify your script enough to work for me, I'm not at that level yet I'm afraid... I'd appreciate it a lot

Comment: @SqueezCZ Alright, I've updated the post with your JSFiddle version.

Comment: @ShadowScripter - This is nearly it! We both stated it in our EDIT info, that the "return to full width while it's being animated" functionality has yet to be created. Do you think there is some not overly complicated solution to that?

Comment: @SqueezCZ I've got this [example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgrxH/3/) that should work, I'm wondering if it's your HTML/CSS combination that's messing it up.

Comment: @ShadowScripter I achieved the same result - the sliding box ending up in the edge of screen... I won't delve into it any deeper (since nobody's going to pay me for that), the current version will more than suffice. Thank you once again, you've been of great help!

Comment: @ShadowScripter I noticed one thing - in the first edit jsfiddle you used "xyz.is(':animating')" and in the second one you used "xyz.attr('animating')" - Am I missing something? It doesn't look like these two attributes even exist (it's even throwing an error in old IEs - And when I remove this parameters from the IF{}, it still works.

Comment: @SqueezCZ Javascript, and by extension JQuery, can create custom attributes. If you click the link for "`.attr()`" in my answers subheading "references", you'll find the documentation for it. As for the `.is(":animating")` or rather `.is(":animated")` as it should say, that's just another tag from the JQuery. [You can read more about it here](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/)